# check and uncheck checkbox when click on label through jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want simple toggle type button. I got it but have some problem. on click label check box checked but unable to check remaining checkbox. I used class because I have unknown number of check box through asp repeater.

my HTML is`enter code here`

```js
$(".labcbox").click(function () {
  var selectedIndex = $('.labcbox').index($(this));
  if ($(".toggin").is(':checked')) {
    $(".toggin")[selectedIndex].checked = false;
  }
  else {
    $(".toggin")[selectedIndex].checked = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>  
    <td>CheckBox toggle</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggin" />
      <label class="labcbox"></label>
      <div class="divmark">
        Hypertention
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CheckBox toggle</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggin" />
      <label class="labcbox"></label>
      <div class="divmark">
        Hypertention
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's not clear if you need to check all the boxes by clicking only one... Anyway I posted an answer, hope it helps...

Comment: See detail Here https://jsfiddle.net/9soqL8wt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/pLq5ep80/

```js
$(".labcbox").click(function () {
  $(this).siblings('input.toggin').prop('checked', !$(this).siblings('input.toggin').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>CheckBox toggle</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggin" />
      <label class="labcbox">Checkbox 1</label>
      <div class="divmark">
        Hypertention
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CheckBox toggle</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggin" />
      <label class="labcbox">Checkbox 2</label>
      <div class="divmark">
        Hypertention
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Bro its working till now and I hope also working on rest.  For Others out put is not look like as shown in snippet its toggle effect check box with UI.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to use jQuery, you can simply wrap your checkbox in the `label` tag.

```html
<label>Click to check
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```